# karate request header validation

Tags: request, http-headers, karate

Would like to be able to assertions to validate that the request header set matches as expected to help validate tests are correctly setting content types supported.

Checked documentation, github issues, stackoverflow, google

```
Given url myUrl
And params myParams
And headers myHeaders
And header Authorization = babylonAuth
And request historyPostPayload
When method POST
Then status 200

* match requestHeaders.contains({'Content-Type': ''})
```

Any way to do this now, or is this a feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the request header, a very rare need. Yes this is possible by referring to the `karate.prevRequest`, documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-prevrequest

So this should be what you are looking for:

```
* def contentType = karate.prevRequest.headers['Content-Type'][0]
* match contentType contains 'application/json'
```

Have a look at this example: [`encoding.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/encoding/encoding.feature)

Comment: latest version have 'match header' like `Then match header Content-Type == 'application/json'` https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-header

Comment: @TokuhiroMatsuno yes but what you are referring to is for the *response* header which is what people need 99% of the time. the question is for the *request* header.

Comment: Will this solution work for old as well as new versions?

Answer (score 0):

`And set headers.Authorization = value` Maybe using Scenario Outline please check the API example in my project `https://github.com/SuriKarate/LogInUI/tree/main`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).